# Dynamically specify which method to use based on a template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I have a method which is simplified to this

```
template<typename t,typename u>
std::shared_ptr<bar> MyClass::getFunct(std::string SomeStr)
{
    .....
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<foo> > j;
    ....
    std::shared_ptr<u> collection(new u());
    for (auto val : j){
    val.second->getMethodA() //Will return object of type t <----LINE A
    }
}
```

Now I am using it as

```
getFunct<FirstType>("SomeString")
getFunct<SecondType>("SomeString")
getFunct<ThirdType>("SomeString")
```

Now `val.second` in Line A
has 3 methods in it

```
val.second->getMethodA() //returns a type of FirstType
val.second->getMethodB() //returns a type of SecondType
val.second->getMethodC() //returns a type of ThirdType
```

Currently i am using 
 `val.second->getMethodA()` with template type  `FirstType`

is there anyway for me to specify to use `getMethodB` if template type is `SecondType`
and use `getMethodC` if template type is `ThirdType`

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem. What is the design issue you're trying to solve? Binding functions to object is possible via `std::bind()`

Comment: let me fix that sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to replace the three `getMethodX` member functions with a single template function `template<class T> T foo::getMethod()`. Then create specializations for each type, if needed.

But if that is not appropriate for the design, then you can use a wrapper function instead:

```
template<class T>
struct helper {};

template<>
struct helper<FirstType> {
    static FirstType getMethod(foo& f) {
        return f.getMethodA();
    }
};
// repeat specializations for other member functions
```

Comment: Yeah looks like i will have to implement something like this

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 you can use `constexpr if`:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) foo(Bar& bar){
   if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,FirstType>){
       return bar.getMethodA();
   }
   if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,SecondType>){
       return bar.getMethodB();
   }
   if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,ThirdType>){
       return bar.getMethodC();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of C++17 I would probably go for something simple like this:

```
template <typename T> struct type {};

struct select
{
    bar &b;
    decltype(auto) operator()(type<FirstType>) const { return b.getMethodA(); }
    decltype(auto) operator()(type<SecondType>) const { return b.getMethodB(); }
    decltype(auto) operator()(type<ThirdType>) const { return b.getMethodC(); }
};
select{*val.second}(type<T>{});
```

In the context of your example:

```
template <typename T> struct type {};

template<typename t,typename u>
std::shared_ptr<bar> MyClass::getFunct(std::string SomeStr)
{
    .....
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<foo> > j;
    ....
    for (auto val : j) {
        struct select {
            bar &b;
            decltype(auto) operator()(type<FirstType>) const { return b.getMethodA(); }
            decltype(auto) operator()(type<SecondType>) const { return b.getMethodB(); }
            decltype(auto) operator()(type<ThirdType>) const { return b.getMethodC(); }
        };
        select{*val.second}(type<t>{});
    }
}
```